# Enum value was not found - "Requested Value Blood A was not found"

Tags: vb.net, enums

This is my vb - XML

```
  Public Enum BloodType
  <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Blood A")>  _
  Blood A
```

This is where I am trying to get Blood A

```
  ([Enum].Parse(GetType(Bloodtype), getData.code)
```

getcode is query and its returning integer - this part is returning the correct number.

I tried getName instead of Parse and no luck! the strange thing the above line worked for some fields

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: It's [a bit more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990069/get-element-of-an-enum-by-sending-xmlenumattribute-c). You'll have to loop all element and get the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error: enum items (and indeed all identifiers) can not contain spaces.

**Does not compile:**

```
Public Enum BloodType
  <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Blood A")> _
  Blood A
End Enum
```

**Compiles:**

```
Public Enum BloodType
  <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Blood A")> _
  Blood_A
End Enum
```