# C# Xml deserialize XmlAttribute by value of attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've been trying to read an oddly constructed XML file and have come up against a wall. I need to deserialize the XML into data structures in my C# program. A sample of the XML being:

```
<object name="CAU_17_163" kind="project" states="expanded">
  <fields>
    <field name="coordinate-system-internal" data="WGS84" kind="string"/>
    <field name="min-longitude" data="-67.55643521" kind="double"/>
    <field name="min-latitude" data="45.09374232" kind="double"/>
    <field name="min-altitude" data="550.094" kind="double" unit="m"/>
    <field name="max-longitude" data="-66.52992272" kind="double"/>
    <field name="max-latitude" data="45.86876855" kind="double"/>
    <field name="max-altitude" data="1400.954" kind="double" unit="m"/>
    <field name="pop" data="0.917266016 0.398275101 0.000000000 0.000000000 -0.285868639 0.658383080 0.696283592 0.000000000 0.277312418 -0.638677277 0.717766786 0.000000000 1771794.580394641 -4080614.005124380 4555229.910096285 1.000000000 " kind="double[4][4]"/>
    <field name="pop-acquisition" data="0.917266016 0.398275101 0.000000000 0.000000000 -0.285868639 0.658383080 0.696283592 0.000000000 0.277312418 -0.638677277 0.717766786 0.000000000 1771794.580394641 -4080614.005124380 4555229.910096285 1.000000000 " kind="double[4][4]"/>
  </fields>
```

And my C# structures are as follows:

A class to allow me to grab the value of the "data" attribute

```
    public class Data<T>
    {
        T dataAttr;

        [XmlAttribute("data")]
        public T DataAttr { get => dataAttr; set => dataAttr = value; }
    }
```

A structure to contain the entire "project" object

```
    [XmlRoot("object")]
    public struct RPPProject
    {
        string name;
        RPPProjectFields fields;

        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
        [XmlAttribute("fields")]
        public RPPProjectFields Fields { get => fields; set => fields = value; }
    }
```

A structure to contain the fields within the the  tag

```
    [XmlRoot("fields")]
    public struct RPPProjectFields
    {
        //Project fields
        Data<string> coordinate_system_internal;
        Data<double> min_longitude;
        Data<double> min_latitude;
        Data<double> min_altitude;
        Data<double> max_longitude;
        Data<double> max_latitude;
        Data<double> max_altitude;
        Data<double[]> pop; //[4][4]
        Data<double[]> pop_acquisition; //[4][4]

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "coordinate-system-internal")]
        public Data<string> Coordinate_system_internal { get => coordinate_system_internal; set => coordinate_system_internal = value; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "min-longitude")]
        public Data<double> Min_longitude { get => min_longitude; set => min_longitude = value; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "min-latitude")]
        public Data<double> Min_latitude { get => min_latitude; set => min_latitude = value; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "min-altitude")]
        public Data<double> Min_altitude { get => min_altitude; set => min_altitude = value; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "max-longitude")]
        public Data<double> Max_longitude { get => max_longitude; set => max_longitude = value; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "max-latitude")]
        public Data<double> Max_latitude { get => max_latitude; set => max_latitude = value; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "max-altitude")]
        public Data<double> Max_altitude { get => max_altitude; set => max_altitude = value; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "pop")]
        public Data<double[]> Pop { get => pop; set => pop = value; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "pop-acquisition")]
        public Data<double[]> Pop_acquisition { get => pop_acquisition; set => pop_acquisition = value; }
    }
```

The issue is that the "name" attribute of the  is not what is registered as the name of the  node and therefor the syntax of [XmlElement(ElementName = "coordinate-system-internal")] doesn't work. I'm stumped. Basically what I need to do is be able to specify the value of the "name" attribute as the way to deserialize the into the different project fields, storing the "data" value within the specified variable.

Comment: Do you know the set of `<field>` elements in advance, or do you want a flexible structure that allows for any collection of fields?

Comment: In the specific case above I know them ahead of time; but further on in the XML a flexible structure would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a sequence of elements like the following:

```
<field name="min-longitude" data="-67.55643521" kind="double"/>
```

And you would like to interpret them as polymorphically specifying different types of values, depending upon the value of the `kind` attribute.

Unfortunately, out of the box `XmlSerializer` does not support polymorphic deserialization using an arbitrary attribute such as `kind`.  Instead it supports using the w3c standard attribute [`xsi:type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) to specify element type, as explained in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx).

However, if we simply consider the attribute `data` to be a string, the XML for each `<field>` element actually has a fixed schema, with the `unit` attribute being optional.  Thus you could deserialize your XML into the following [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and then later convert the field values into their expected types:

```
public abstract class RPPItemBase
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("kind")]
    public string Kind { get; set; }

    bool ShouldSerializeKind() { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Kind); }
}

[XmlRoot("object")]
public class RPPProjectDTO : RPPItemBase
{
    public RPPProjectDTO() { this.Kind = "project"; }

    [XmlAttribute("states")]
    public string States { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("fields")]
    public RPPProjectFieldsDTO Fields { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("fields")]
public class RPPProjectFieldsDTO
{
    [XmlElement("field")]
    public RPPProjectFieldDTO[] Fields { get; set; }
}

public class RPPProjectFieldDTO : RPPItemBase
{
    [XmlAttribute("data")]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeUnit() { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Unit); }
}
```

Sample [fiddle #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VckM8K).

However, from your question it appears you would like some (semi-)automatic way from within serialization to convert typed properties of a c# object from and to a list of `<field name =...>` elements.  Since this is not supported out of the box you will need to add a surrogate `RPPProjectFieldDTO []` property to each type you wish to serialize in this manner, and handle the conversions inside the property getters and setters.  The following would be one prototype implementation:

```
[XmlRoot("object")]
public class RPPProject : RPPItemBase
{
    public RPPProject() { this.Kind = "project"; }

    [XmlAttribute("states")]
    public string States { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("fields")]
    public RPPProjectFields Fields { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("fields")]
[DataContract(Name = "fields")]
public class RPPProjectFields
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    [DataMember(Name = "coordinate-system-internal")]
    public string CoordinateSystemInternal { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    [DataMember(Name = "min-longitude")]
    public double MinLongitude { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    [DataMember(Name = "min-latitude")]
    public double MinLatitude { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    [DataMember(Name = "min-altitude")]
    public DimensionalValue MinAltitude { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    [DataMember(Name = "max-longitude")]
    public double MaxLongitude { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    [DataMember(Name = "max-latitude")]
    public double MaxLatitude { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    [DataMember(Name = "max-altitude")]
    public DimensionalValue MaxAltitude { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    [DataMember(Name = "pop")]
    public double[][] Pop { get; set; } //[4][4]

    [XmlIgnore]
    [DataMember(Name = "pop-acquisition")]
    public double[][] PopAcquisition { get; set; } //[4][4]

    [XmlElement("field")]
    public RPPProjectFieldDTO[] Fields
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetDataContractFields();
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetDataContractFields(value);
        }
    }
}

public enum Units
{
    [XmlEnum("none")]
    None,
    [XmlEnum("m")]
    Meters,
    [XmlEnum("cm")]
    Centimeters,
    [XmlEnum("mm")]
    Millimeters,
}

// Going with something like the Money Pattern here:
// http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/recursos/fowler-ap/Analysis%20Pattern%20Quantity.htm
// You may want to implement addition, subtraction, comparison and so on.

public struct DimensionalValue
{
    readonly Units units;
    readonly double value;

    public DimensionalValue(Units units, double value)
    {
        this.units = units;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Units Units { get { return units; } }

    public double Value { get { return value; } }
}

public interface IFieldDTOParser
{
    Regex Regex { get; }

    bool TryCreateDTO(object obj, out RPPProjectFieldDTO field);

    object Parse(RPPProjectFieldDTO field, Match match);
}

class StringParser : IFieldDTOParser
{
    readonly Regex regex = new Regex("^string$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

    #region IFieldDTOParser Members

    public Regex Regex { get { return regex; } }

    public bool TryCreateDTO(object obj, out RPPProjectFieldDTO field)
    {
        if (obj is string)
        {
            field = new RPPProjectFieldDTO { Data = (string)obj, Kind = "string"};
            return true;
        }
        field = null;
        return false;
    }

    public object Parse(RPPProjectFieldDTO field, Match match)
    {
        return field.Data;
    }

    #endregion
}

class DoubleParser : IFieldDTOParser
{
    readonly Regex regex = new Regex("^double$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

    #region IFieldDTOParser Members

    public Regex Regex { get { return regex; } }

    public bool TryCreateDTO(object obj, out RPPProjectFieldDTO field)
    {
        if (obj is double)
        {
            field = new RPPProjectFieldDTO { Data = XmlConvert.ToString((double)obj), Kind = "double"};
            return true;
        }
        else if (obj is DimensionalValue)
        {
            var value = (DimensionalValue)obj;

            field = new RPPProjectFieldDTO { Data = XmlConvert.ToString(value.Value), Kind = "double", Unit = value.Units.ToXmlValue() };
            return true;
        }
        field = null;
        return false;
    }

    public object Parse(RPPProjectFieldDTO field, Match match)
    {
        var value = XmlConvert.ToDouble(field.Data);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.Unit))
            return value;
        var unit = field.Unit.FromXmlValue<Units>();
        return new DimensionalValue(unit, value);

    }

    #endregion
}

class Double2DArrayParser : IFieldDTOParser
{
    readonly Regex regex = new Regex("^double\\[([0-9]+)\\]\\[([0-9]+)\\]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

    #region IFieldDTOParser Members

    public Regex Regex { get { return regex; } }

    public bool TryCreateDTO(object obj, out RPPProjectFieldDTO field)
    {
        if (obj is double[][])
        {
            var value = (double[][])obj;
            var nCols = value.GetLength(0);
            var rowLengths = value.Select(a => a == null ? 0 : a.Length).Distinct().ToArray();
            if (rowLengths.Length == 0)
            {
                field = new RPPProjectFieldDTO { Data = "", Kind = string.Format("double[{0}][{1}]", XmlConvert.ToString(nCols), "0")};
                return true;
            }
            else if (rowLengths.Length == 1)
            {
                field = new RPPProjectFieldDTO 
                { 
                    Data = String.Join(" ", value.SelectMany(a => a).Select(v => XmlConvert.ToString(v))),
                    Kind = string.Format("double[{0}][{1}]", XmlConvert.ToString(nCols), XmlConvert.ToString(rowLengths[0])) 
                };
                return true;
            }
        }
        field = null;
        return false;
    }

    public object Parse(RPPProjectFieldDTO field, Match match)
    {
        var nRows = XmlConvert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
        var nCols = XmlConvert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);

        var array = new double[nRows][];

        var values = field.Data.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int iRow = 0, iValue = 0; iRow < nRows; iRow++)
        {
            array[iRow] = new double[nCols];
            for (int iCol = 0; iCol < nCols; iCol++)
            {
                if (iValue < values.Length)
                    array[iRow][iCol] = XmlConvert.ToDouble(values[iValue++]);
            }
        }

        return array;
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class FieldDTOExtensions
{
    readonly static IFieldDTOParser[] parsers = new IFieldDTOParser[]
    {
        new StringParser(),
        new DoubleParser(),
        new Double2DArrayParser(),
    };

    public static void SetDataContractFields<T>(this T @this, RPPProjectFieldDTO [] value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return;
        var lookup = value.ToDictionary(f => f.Name, f => f.Parse<object>());
        var query = from p in @this.GetType().GetProperties()
                    where p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0
                    let a = p.GetCustomAttributes<DataMemberAttribute>().SingleOrDefault()
                    where a != null
                    select new { Property = p, Name = a.Name };
        foreach (var property in query)
        {
            object item;
            if (lookup.TryGetValue(property.Name, out item))
            {
                property.Property.SetValue(@this, item, null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static RPPProjectFieldDTO[] GetDataContractFields<T>(this T @this)
    {
        var query = from p in @this.GetType().GetProperties()
                    where p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0
                    let a = p.GetCustomAttributes<DataMemberAttribute>().SingleOrDefault()
                    where a != null
                    let v = p.GetValue(@this, null)
                    where v != null
                    select FieldDTOExtensions.ToDTO(v, a.Name);
        return query.ToArray();
    }

    public static T Parse<T>(this RPPProjectFieldDTO field)
    {
        foreach (var parser in parsers)
        {
            var match = parser.Regex.Match(field.Kind);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                return (T)parser.Parse(field, match);
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unsupported object {0}", field.Kind));
    }

    public static RPPProjectFieldDTO ToDTO(object obj, string name)
    {
        RPPProjectFieldDTO field;
        foreach (var parser in parsers)
        {
            if (parser.TryCreateDTO(obj, out field))
            {
                field.Name = name;
                return field;
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unsupported object {0}", obj));
    }
}

// Taken from 
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990069/get-element-of-an-enum-by-sending-xmlenumattribute-c

public static partial class XmlExtensions
{
    static XmlExtensions()
    {
        noStandardNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        noStandardNamespaces.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd attributes.
    }

    readonly static XmlSerializerNamespaces noStandardNamespaces;
    internal const string RootNamespace = "XmlExtensions";
    internal const string RootName = "Root";

    public static TEnum FromXmlValue<TEnum>(this string xml) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable
    {
        var element = new XElement(XName.Get(RootName, RootNamespace), xml);
        return element.Deserialize<XmlExtensionsEnumWrapper<TEnum>>(null).Value;
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XContainer element, XmlSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            object result = (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
                return (T)result;
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public static string ToXmlValue<TEnum>(this TEnum value) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable
    {
        var root = new XmlExtensionsEnumWrapper<TEnum> { Value = value };
        return root.SerializeToXElement().Value;
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return obj.SerializeToXElement(null, noStandardNamespaces); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd attributes by default.
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
            (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType())).Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
        var element = doc.Root;
        if (element != null)
            element.Remove();
        return element;
    }
}

[XmlRoot(XmlExtensions.RootName, Namespace = XmlExtensions.RootNamespace)]
[XmlType(IncludeInSchema = false)]
public class XmlExtensionsEnumWrapper<TEnum>
{
    [XmlText]
    public TEnum Value { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- The conventional, typed properties of `RPPProjectFields` are all marked with [`[XmlIgnore]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx).  Instead there is a single surrogate property

  ```
  public RPPProjectFieldDTO[] Fields { get { ... } set { ... } }
  ```

  that is serialized.
- Inside the surrogate property, reflection is used to cycle through all the "regular" properties of `RPPProjectFields` and convert them to objects of type `RPPProjectFieldDTO`.  However the XML names (e.g. `"max-longitude"`) contain a character `-` that is illegal for use in a c# identifier.  Thus it's necessary to specify an alternate name, but the properties cannot be marked with `[XmlElement("Alternate Name")]` since they are already marked with `[XmlIgnore]`.  So I instead used [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) to specify the alternate names.
- Some of your `double` values have units, e.g. `<field name="min-altitude" data="550.094" kind="double" unit="m"/>`  To handle this I introduced a container struct `DimensionalValue`.  The idea would be to follow the [quantity pattern](https://web.archive.org/web/20121224045923/http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html) (sometimes called the [money pattern](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/837791/money-pattern)) using this struct.

Sample [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dyh57O) which, sadly, doesn't compile because .NET Fiddle doesn't support System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.